# Java isn't automatically including class

Tags: java

This seems like a simple problem, but somehow I'm having issues with this code. I'm getting back into Java after a few years, and I'm making a 2D game. In it, I have a main driver class called `SnakeGame` that loads a new instance of the class `GameBoard`.

**SnakeGame.java**

```
package snake2;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SnakeGame extends JFrame {

public SnakeGame() {
    add(new GameBoard());

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(320, 340);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Snake Game");

    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SnakeGame();
}
}
```

In the same directory lies **GameBoard.java**, which has a constructer with no required parameters:

```
public GameBoard() {
    [... more code ...]
}
```

### Edit

Both `GameBoard.java` and `SnakeGame.java` have `package snake2;` at the first line of their files.

However, I keep receiving the following error:

```
SnakeGame.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GameBoard
location: class snake2.SnakeGame
    add(new GameBoard());
            ^
1 error
```

### Edit #2

I've tried to add it to my class path, using `java -cp . GameBoard` after `javac`. Here's the first line of the terminal's scary looking and unnecessarily verbose response:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: GameBoard (wrong name: snake2/GameBoard)
```

This is as if I've misspelled the class, or misspelled a file name. Although, to my knowledge, I haven't done either. Is there some other problem with my code that I haven't noticed?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: did you put the same package statement inside the GameBoard class file ?

Comment: Show us the top of your Gameboard class.

Comment: @Chromium : Are you compiling outside the package or inside it ?

Comment: Tell us about / show us your invocation environment - are you running command-line `java`? what parameters? what's your current directory? etc. (based on @hbtest answer suggesting `classpath`)

Comment: @Kal/Amine: I've edited my question, both are using `package snake2;`.

Comment: @Chromium Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Stephen: I'm running `java`, and all the files are in the same directory. @Jverstry I'm actually using the TextMate Java plugin, although I get the same error when using `java`, as the plugin uses `java` to execute.

Comment: @Chromium, FYI, only the first @-notification in any comment actually sends a notification, so you never notified Jverstry (or Amine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides being in the same directory, do you have a `package` statement in GameBoard.java?

---

**Edit** for *running* the program --

> @Stephen: I'm running java, and all the files are in the same directory.

From @kbolino

> You must put your source files in a snake2 directory and run javac from the parent directory [...]

You must also *invoke* java, not just javac, with the correct package and classpath.

Examples that worked for me, after creating SnakeGame and GameBoard stubs:

1. Current dir is `projects` which is the parent of the `snake2` dir where the files are:
   `java snake2.SnakeGame`
2. Current dir is `snake2` where I was editing the files:
   `java -cp .. snake2.SnakeGame`

For case #2 since you're *in* the package dir you have to put the *parent* dir in the classpath.

.

Adding a ridiculous amount of information showing my session with both the `javac` compile command and `java` run. You don't need `-cp` for compiling as suggested by some.

---

```
[~/tests/java/snake2]$ pwd
/home/stephenp/tests/java/snake2

[~/tests/java/snake2]$ cat GameBoard.java

package snake2;

class GameBoard {

    private static int instanceCount = 0;

    GameBoard() {
        GameBoard.instanceCount++;
    }

    void howMany() {
        System.out.println(instanceCount + " GameBoards have been created.");
    }
}

[~/tests/java/snake2]$ cat SnakeGame.java

package snake2;

public class SnakeGame {

    private GameBoard board = null;

    public SnakeGame() {
        this.board = new GameBoard();
    }

    void report(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SnakeGame game = new SnakeGame();
        game.report("I exist");
        game.board.howMany();
    }
}


[~/tests/java/snake2]$ ls -1
GameBoard.java
SnakeGame.java

[~/tests/java/snake2]$ javac *.java

[~/tests/java/snake2]$ ls -1
GameBoard.class
GameBoard.java
SnakeGame.class
SnakeGame.java

[~/tests/java/snake2]$ java SnakeGame
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SnakeGame (wrong name: snake2/SnakeGame)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)

[~/tests/java/snake2]$ java snake2.SnakeGame
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: snake2/SnakeGame
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: snake2.SnakeGame
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)

[~/tests/java/snake2]$ java -cp .. snake2.SnakeGame
I exist
1 GameBoards have been created.
```

---

**Packaging**

Package up your application in a `.jar` file along with a Manifest that specifies the main class to run, then you can run your program just using

```
java -jar myprogram.jar
```

To do that, create a file `Manifest.txt` in the directory above your package directory

```
[~/tests/java/snake2]$ cd ..

[~/tests/java]$ ls -1F
Manifest.txt
snake2/

[~/tests/java]$ cat Manifest.txt
Main-Class: snake2.SnakeGame

[~/tests/java]$ jar cfm myprogram.jar Manifest.txt snake2/*.class

[~/tests/java]$ jar tf myprogram.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
snake2/GameBoard.class
snake2/SnakeGame.class
```

You can also wrap a script (shell script, batch file, etc.) around that so you just run `myprogram` and it runs `java -jar myprogram.jar`

This would all be part of your build process.

Comment: Yes, both `GameBoard.java` and `SnakeGame.java` have at the first line the statement `package snake2;`.

Comment: @Chromium - updated my answer. I got the same error as you when I ran `java` the way I was guessing you might have ran it.

Comment: Hey, looks like I wasn't the only one who decided to do a mockup. Have an upvote!

Comment: This was the best answer, and it worked- however, is there an easier permanent solution so I don't have to type `java -cp .. snake2.SnakeGame` every time?

Comment: @Chromium - yes, there are several ways, but most of the time people end up writing a *nix shell script, windows `.bat` or `.cmd` file, or create a "shortcut" that can specify command line parameters and a working directory (in Win you can set the "Start in:" property of a shortcut). I like `.jar` files. I'll add an example of jar packaging to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities:

- Non-printing and/or special characters snuck into one of your files and makes the `GameBoard` identifiers different even though they look the same
- One or more of your files has character encoding issues that are tripping up the compiler
- `GameBoard` does not inherit from `java.awt.Component`, which is necessary for `add()` to work
- <strike>You omitted the `public` modifier in front of `class GameBoard`</strike>
- <strike>You omitted the `package snake2` statement at the top of GameBoard.java</strike>

[This page](http://javafixer.org/cannot-find-symbol.php) lists some common causes of the "cannot find symbol" error, although it may not explain your particular error.

**EDIT** :
kbolino may be onto something, although his answer was syntactically incorrect. I made a mockup on my machine, and the following works for me:

```
(any parent directories)
  |
  |--snake2
       |
       |--SnakeGame.java
       |--GameBoard.java
```

and then running, from inside the `snake2` directory,

```
javac SnakeGame.java GameBoard.java
```

followed by returning to `snake2`'s parent directory and running

```
java snake2/SnakeGame
```

**EDIT 2**
In a comment, the OP asked "how come `java SnakeGame` doesn't work within the snake2 folder, but `java snake2/SnakeGame` works in the parent directory?"

The question is well-meaning, but misleading. `snake2` in that command is part of the name, not a path. If you **are** in the `snake2` folder, `java -cp .. snake2/SnakeGame` still works. For similar reasons, `javac -cp snake2 snake2/SnakeGame.java snake2/GameBoard.java` also works when you are in `snake2`'s parent directory.

That said, `java snake2/SnakeGame` alone (still from inside the `snake2` folder) does not work. This is because

> Remember when using a classpath, the last directory in the path must be the super-directory of the *root* directory for the package. (SCJP 6 guide, Sierra & Bates, p804)

Comment: Nope, `class GameBoard` is defined as `public class GameBoard`. Good idea though, I thought of that too.

Comment: How would I check for character encoding/special character issues? The code looks fine to me while in TextMate.

Comment: If you typed everything out by hand in TextMate, it's probably not a strange-character issue. I don't know that program, but I would guess that the Save As dialog or some Options box contains a field that shows the encoding you're using.

Comment: It's `UTF8` with `LF` line endings.

Comment: Upvoted- but how come `java SnakeGame` doesn't work within the snake2 folder, but `java snake2/SnakeGame` works in the parent directory?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if it is your problem. But in the API from JAVA, if you search for JFrame, in the description says something like this:

> The JFrame class is slightly incompatible with Frame. Like all other JFC/Swing top-level containers, a JFrame contains a JRootPane as its only child. The content pane provided by the root pane should, as a rule, contain all the non-menu components displayed by the JFrame. This is different from the AWT Frame case. For example, to add a child to an AWT frame you'd write:

```
   frame.add(child);
```

> However using JFrame you need to add the child to the JFrame's content pane instead:

```
   frame.getContentPane().add(child);
```

Could you try it?

Comment: Tried it- same error. It seems that the issue isn't with the frame, it's just that Java doesn't seem to recognize the `GameBoard` class's existence.

Comment: Even though this is a wrong answer for this question, it's a good catch from a Swing perspective!

Comment: Ok, then the only thing that i can think of are already told. Check the packet declaration, check that the file is there, check that the visibility is correct (the class is not `private`), check the compiling (classpath, etc)... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The GameBoard that you want to add to your `JFrame` SnakeGame must inherit from `java.awt.Container`, e.g. `JPanel`.

Moreover, your code creates two GameBoard instances, one for the print, and one for the add method. It would be more efficient if you've created a variable:

```
GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard();
System.out.println(gameBoard);
add(gameBoard );
```

In your case, The GameBoard instance you print and the instance you add to the JFrame are two different ones.

Comment: True- however, this doesn't solve the problem, because it doesn't matter how I try to instantiate the class, Java acts like it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You must put your source files in a snake2 directory and run javac from the parent directory with the following invocation:

```
javac snake2/*.java
```

In general, your directory structure must correspond to your package names.

Comment: Tried changing directory structure to mirror package name aaaaaannnndd... no cigar, same error. Thanks though.

Comment: You need to run the program as `java snake2.SnakeGame`

Comment: Tried that, and received the same `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: snake2/SnakeGame` error.

Comment: You're getting a couple of different errors, actually.  Try erasing all of your generated .class files, recompiling with `javac snake2/*.java`, and then re-running with `java snake2.SnakeGame`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the classpath. Usually when I run into problems like this it is a classpath problem. I know your situation isn't to complicated but check anyways.

Also, if you are using eclipse, try cleaning your workspace. Sometimes weird quirks like this are worked out through that.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can think of is if the `package` in `GameBoard` is not defined properly. Or, have you tried clean and recompile all?

Answer (score 0):

It is funny what potential such a trivial problem has with experienced Java developers.

I assume you are not using any IDE and write your classes in some text editor and compile them nicely from command line using javac, are you not?:)

You obviously miss . (dot, a symbol for the current folder) from your CLASSPATH. Either set CLASSPATH as a system variable or use following with javac:

```
javac -cp . SnakeGame
```

Comment: Ran that and got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SnakeGame (wrong name: snake2/SnakeGame)`.

Comment: Okay. my bad. Run 'javac *.java' from the snake2 folder. Should also have to include swing jar in classpath if you really do not have it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using command line?

have you complied GameBoard first?

you should try

```
javac *.java
```

from your "snake2" directory

Edit: after this move one level up (`cd..`) the run 
`java snake2/SnakeGame`

Comment: Already tried, thanks, but same error. With the command line though, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error.

Comment: javac gives `file not found error`, not `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error. you are trying to use java command first, but first you should compile it with javac then use java command as `java -cp . snake2/SnakeGame` from the parent directory of "snake2"

Comment: I'm well aware of that. What I'm saying is, `javac` runs fine. I get the `NoClassDefFoundError` when I run java on `SnakeBoard`.

Comment: are you runing java command from the parent directory of "snake2", ie the directory containing snake2?  and you have to mention the package in command also `java snake2/SnakeGame` (not `SnakeBoard`)

Comment: I'm running `java *.java` from within snake2.

Comment: no you have to run `javac *.java` from within snake2, then go one level up (`cd..`) then run `java snake2/SnakeGame`.

Comment: @Ankur - you need to use a dot `.` not a slash `/` - see my updated answer.